# How to avoid for loop and null comparison to set initial value of a property to a default value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Currently I have written following code in my application:

```
foreach (var country in model.Countries)
{
    if (country.Cities == null)
        country.Cities = new List<City>();
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but this this can still be optimized especially to improve the performance.

Any possibility or other way to avoid for loop, and assign "country.Cities" to an empty City list when the Cities is null. I mean, if we can achieve this in a single command only, rather than iterating each items for performing the same operation?

I am not having C# 7.0 at this time, so I would like to know a more efficient solution by keeping that in consideration.

Comment: *to improve performance*? no, that's perfectly fine

Comment: without real context why not just change the country class so that when its crated it creates an empty cities list..

Comment: Almost every person asking a performance related question should read this first: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: do you have control over the creation of the model? or is it loaded from a database or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the list in the model's class constructor:

```
public class Country
{
     Country()
     {
         Cities = new List<City>();
     }

     public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

This way you don't even need to do your `foreach` statements since the list is automatically instantiated upon `Country` class instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

You must initialise it in your model. If you use C#6 you can do it as follows, if lower version you can do that in constructor.

```
public class Country
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; } = new List<City>();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing related to performance regarding this.

As others pointed instantiate in constructor, but another thing you can do here is if you want to avoid repetition is in the getter of `Cities` you can make sure to return an instance of `List<City>` if it is `null` :

```
public class Country
{
   private List<City> cities = null;

   public List<City> Cities
   {

      get
        {
            if(cities == null)
                 cities = new List<City>();
           return cities;
        }
     set
       {
           cities = value;
       }

   } 
}
```